# Is a Javascript function (without promises) guaranteed to run without interruption?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
let x = 1
setInterval(() => x += 1, 1000)
function f() {
    console.log(x)
    console.log(x)
}
```

When the function is called, are two outputs guaranteed to be the same? Or can the setInterval trigger between these two?

I have tried to search MDN web docs on this topic, but I'm unfamiliar with the concept and unsure which pages I should be looking for.

Comment: `When the function is called, are two outputs guaranteed to be the same?` Yes.

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed to run without interruption when you consider stuff like power outages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JavaScript process can be interrupted at any time by the CPU switching threads. However, JavaScript itself is single-threaded, and a function will never be interrupted by some other part of your application.

Extending your code slightly:

```
let x = 1
setInterval(() => x += 1, 1000)
function f() {
    console.log(x)
    while(1) { /* Program blocks forever, setInteral is never invoked again */ }
    console.log(x)
}
```

This program will cause the JavaScript runtime to hang forever, and your `setInterval` callback will never run. However the computer will continue to run other programs around yours, periodically pausing the JavaScript runtime so other processes can use the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

The `setInterval` callback won’t run until the call stack is empty, so I would expect `x` to be consistent at the time of each console call.

(I say “at the time of the call” because `console.log` output itself is not necessarily synchronous, making it possible to modify an object between the time console.log is invoked and the time that output actually appears in the console.)